# Unity2D - collide with objects while moving to a position

Tags: c#, collision-detection, unity, rigidbody

How do I get my character to collide with other objects while moving to a position?

All I've managed to do is change the position, it only collides if the character is not moving, it's like he is moving behind.

```
void Update () {

    foreach(Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
        {
            worldCoordinates = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            posi.x = worldCoordinates.x;
            posi.y = worldCoordinates.y;
            //transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, posi, speed);
            //transform.Translate(0,32.4,0);
            //rb.MovePosition(posi);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps objects have different Z positions?

Comment: For moving to a position you can use lerp method. Then use OnCollisionEnter2D() to check collisions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, all your physics related stuff should be done in `FixedUpdate` method and not in `Update` method.

`Update` is called every frame, while `FixedUpdate` is called at fixed interval. When you ask Physics movement computation in `FixedUpdate` Unity will predict the new position in `Update` until it'll be able to compute the actual position in the next `FixedUpdate` (ie: it explains why fast moving objects are usually not stopped by walls. Because the FixedUpdate happens too soon or too late to compute the collision).

Also, if you want to move a `GameObject` that has a `RigidBody` attached don't move it using its `Transform`, do it using its `RigidBody`.

So instead of setting `transform.position` use directly `rb.MovePosition`. This will teleport your gameObject from its current position to the desired position every `FixedUpdate`. If it's not smooth enough, you can Lerp between the two positions in the `Update` method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @lvictorino answer, maybe what you're looking for is in fact the [`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) method.

I'm not exactly familiar on how it could work with Unity, but roughly, what you could do is

```
// Rough pseudocode
difference = touchPosition -  objectPosition

distance = difference.lenght
direction = difference.normalize

radiusForMaxForce = 50 // tweak this value, above that distance maxForce will be used as-is, 
                       // otherwise it will be scaled down
maxForce = 25 // tweak this value according to your needs

if distance > radiusForMaxForce
  distance = radiusForMaxForce

forceRatio = distance / radiusForMaxForce

thrust = forceRatio * maxForce
forceVector = direction * thrust

rb.AddForce(forceVector)
```

If your target game object encounters other rigid body, the physics simulation should be respected: free bodies will be pushed around, and there is not going to be inter-penetration.